# JSON Call to MySQL Improperly Handling Variable

Tags: mysql, json, variables, fetch

I'm trying to set-up open-source software called pushpool which is essentially a JSON rpc server and for some reason I keep receiving "mysql pwdb query failed at fetch" when attempting worker authentication.

Here's the run-down:

OS is Ubuntu
Running MySql
Front-end: open-source software called "SimpleCoin"
Miners connect fine but pushpool returns "mysql pwdb query failed at fetch" when connecting because mysql is trying to read username as "?"

mysql.log shows pushpool trying to pass the following statement:

`SELECT password FROM pool_worker WHERE username = ?`

Which is being called by pushpool's server.json file in this section (user/pass info has been edited):

```
# database settings
     "database" : {
               "engine" : "mysql",

               # 'host' defaults to localhost, if not specified
               # "host" : "localhost",

               # 'port' uses proper default port for the DB engine,
               # if not specified
               "port" : "3306",

               "name" : "simplecoin",
               "username" : "SuperCoolUsername",
               "password" : "SuperSecretPassword",
               "sharelog" : true,
               "stmt.pwdb":"SELECT password FROM pool_worker WHERE username = ?",

               "stmt.sharelog":"INSERT INTO shares (rem_host, username, our_result, upstream_result, reason, solution) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
    },
```

Worker/pass info has been added to table "pool_worker".

It would seem to me that the json client doesn't like the way the variable is being handled in:

`"stmt.pwdb":"SELECT password FROM pool_worker WHERE username = ?",`

Since the "?" isn't being properly replaced by the connecting miner's username and the statement otherwise works fine when tested from mysql command line with known worker username...

Any ideas on how I can fix the variable so json passes the correct statement to mysql...?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

MySQL call is not improperly handling variable. It's not a bug, rather a confusing error message.

Possible cause: your pool_worker table may be empty (not a single record).

If it worked before then maybe you have re-created the database structure at some point. Re-creating usually involves dropping previous table structure and re-creating the new one from scratch. The process also erases all records in that table. Even if the newly created table structure is the same as the old one the records are lost.

If it never worked before, you may have never inserted username and password into pool_worker table.

The fix is simple: insert at least one record of username and password in the pool_worker table (not-null strings).

Once at least one record username and password is inserted the message "mysql pwdb query failed at fetch" should not appear again.